# How can I disable a date range in material date range picker?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

Here I have a `DateRangePicker` using the [Material library](https://m2.material.io/components/date-pickers/android#date-range-pickers).

```
 val dateRangePicker =
                    MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
                    .setTitleText(getString(R.string.calendar_select_dates))
                    .setSelection(...)
                    .build()
```

How can I set minDate and maxDate to show me the only range between minDate<...<maxDate? In the documentation, it's mentioned how to disable the previous month but I want to disable the previous and following days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample code to set the min and max dates for restricting the date picker between two dates.

```
 private fun showDatePickerDialog() {

        val constraintsBuilder = CalendarConstraints.Builder()

        // Set the minimum selectable date to a specific date (e.g., January 1, 2000).
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val min = calendar.timeInMillis
        constraintsBuilder.setStart(min)

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10)
        val max = calendar.timeInMillis
        constraintsBuilder.setEnd(max)

        val listValidators =
            arrayListOf(DateValidatorPointForward.from(min), DateValidatorPointBackward.before(max))
        constraintsBuilder.setValidator(CompositeDateValidator.allOf(listValidators))

        val datePickerBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().apply {
            setTitleText(getString(R.string.app_name))
            setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build())
            // Set the initial date to the current date
            val currentTimeMillis = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
            setSelection(currentTimeMillis)
            setInputMode(MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_CALENDAR)
        }
        val datePicker = datePickerBuilder.build()
        datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener { selection ->
            // Get selected date
        }
        // Don't forget to show the dialog
        datePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "datePicker")
    }
```